# Wie sagt man einem Arzt »I would really appreciate your time to help me with my issue«?

Tags: translation, phrase-request, politeness

Ich schreibe einem Arzt und bin mir nicht sicher, wie ich das englische

> I would appreciate your time

auf Deutsch ausdrücken könnte bzw. ob es überhaupt möglich oder üblich ist, so etwas zu schreiben.

Was könnte ich stattdessen noch sagen?

Comment: Wenn du selbst auch Arzt bist, dann am besten mit "Mit kollegialen Grüßen".

Answer (score 3):

Naja, eigentlich kommt es dir ja nicht auf seine Zeit an, sondern auf seinen Rat oder sein Wissen. Dementsprechend würde ich schreiben "Über ihren Rat in dieser Angelegenheit / ihren Kommentar zu meinen Darstellungen / ihre Meinung zu obigem Sachverhalt würde ich mich sehr freuen". Dazu kommt die übliche Grußformel "Mit freundlichen Grüßen".

Answer (score 0):

Es kommt natürlich auf den Zusammenhang an, aber üblich ist so eine Formulierung eher nicht. Du könntest etwas wie

```
Ihre Mühe wüsste ich sehr zu schätzen.
```

oder

```
Ihr Urteil wüsste ich sehr zu schätzen.
```

schreiben.

Comment: Ich will nur extra hoeflich sein aber formal bleiben. Wie endet man normalerweise einen sehr hoeflichen brief an einen Arzt?

Comment: Als Grußformel könnte vielleicht Hochachtungsvoll benutzt werden, sonst etwas Ähnliches wie oben. Eine feste Floskel gibt es meines Wissens nicht.

Comment: Ja genau, das meine ich

Answer (score 0):

Man könnte auch sagen,

> Ich danke Ihnen, dass Sie sich die Zeit nehmen, ...

Natürlich kommt dann eine Grußformel dazu. Beispielsweise

> Ich danke Ihnen, dass Sie sich die Zeit nehmen, ... und verbleibe mit freundlichen Grüßen